# Python - Can't import bcrypt in local app engine dev server

Tags: python, google-app-engine, bcrypt

I am trying to develop a simple forum site for my udacity assignment. It is not a strict requirement to use the bcrypt for password hashing, but I'd like to do it because I also like to know how to use third party libraries which are not provided by Google.

Following instructions provided [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27) (installing a third-party library), I have created a folder named lib, and installed bcrypt library with following command:

```
python -m pip install -t lib/ bcrypt
```

I have the lib folder automatically structred like this:

[image: structre of lib folder]

I also created an appengine_config.py file with following content, as per instructions in above manual:

```
# appengine_config.py
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# add lib folder as vendor directory
vendor.add('lib')
```

At this point, I am unable to import the bcrypt to my scripts. The import commands I tried so far are as follows:

---

```
from lib import bcrypt
```

> ImportError: No module named lib

---

---

```
import bcrypt
```

> ImportError: No module named bcrypt._bcrypt

---

---

```
from lib.bcrypt import bcrypt
```

> ImportError: No module named lib.bcrypt

---

What am I missing?

Comment: second import is enough

Comment: @AvinashRaj It is not working. Gives `ImportError: No module named bcrypt._bcrypt`

Comment: you can't use a module which contain files of c extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Avinash Raj pointed out, and as already pointed out in referenced manual, one cannot use python libraries with c extensions. So I downloaded the [py-bcrypt](https://github.com/erlichmen/py-bcrypt), it worked like a charm.

For any newbie like me who needs it, here is the steps you have to take:

1. Inside your project folder, create a folder called "lib"
2. Extract the zip downloaded from github above, to the folder 'lib'. Do not use
   **-** in your folder name. Name it something like `pybcrypt`
3. Create the `appengine_config.py`file, as outlined in [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27)
4. Import the library to your script, like so: `from pybcrypt import bcrypt`
5. Pat yourself on the back.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another option, you need to setup **Wheel package** before you can import **bcrypt**

```
pip install wheel
```

```
pip install bcrypt
```

`from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt`